# Unlimited join to the same table until exists

Tags: sql, join, mariadb, self-join

I don't even know how to properly name this question. I know how to join the same table, but this situation is slightly different. I'll try to make everything as simple as possible. Here are 2 tables:

`ingredients` (contains ingredient IDs and names)

```
ingredient_id|ingredient_name
1            |Water
2            |Salt
3            |Fancy Sauce
4            |Spices
5            |Pepper
6            |Chili
```

`ingredients_to_ingredients` (contains optional sub-ingredients for each ingredient)

```
ingredient_id|mapped_ingredient_id
3            |1
3            |2
3            |4
4            |5
4            |6
```

I need to get all the sub-ingredients (if any) for specified ingredient. So if I want to get sub-ingredients of #3 (Fancy Sauce), I use:

```
SELECT * FROM ingredients AS main
LEFT JOIN ingredients_to_ingredients AS sub
ON main.ingredient_id=sub.ingredient_id 
LEFT JOIN ingredients
ON sub.mapped_ingredient_id=ingredients.ingredient_id
WHERE main.ingredient_id=3
```

And get the list:

```
Water
Salt
Spices
```

Easy. But as you see, `Spices` contains other sub-ingredients (`Pepper` and `Chili`), and I need to list them as well.

Some will say I can add 2nd sub-query, but there's a catch: there's **no fixed number**. In other words, one ingredient might not have sub-ingredients at all, while another might have lots of sub-sub-sub-ingredients (which would require dozens of sub-queries).

How do I write a query which keeps selecting mapped sub-ingredients as long as any ingredient has sub-ingredients? Now, I just use lots of repeated sub-queries (like dozens of them, just to be sure every possible sub-sub-sub ingredient is included), but query looks ugly and I believe it's not the best way to do it.

Any suggestions how to modify the query above?

P.S. I'm sure someone will say using sub-sub-sub ingredients mapped to themselves is a bad design.  Well, I can't say to restaurant's chief - "don't use sub-ingredients in your ingredients because it's bad design from database point of view". Hope you got the idea why the design is as it is and can't be changed.

Comment: You need in recurse. What is **precise** MySQL version on your server?

Comment: I guess you're looking for a recursive CTE (Common Table Expression).

Comment: @Akina - It's MariaDB 10.4.18.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - thank you for the suggestion, now at least I have an idea what to search for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT *
         FROM ingredients_to_ingredients 
         WHERE ingredient_id = 3
       UNION ALL
         SELECT ingredients_to_ingredients.*
         FROM ingredients_to_ingredients
         JOIN cte ON cte.mapped_ingredient_id = ingredients_to_ingredients.ingredient_id )
SELECT ingredients.ingredient_name
FROM cte
JOIN ingredients ON cte.mapped_ingredient_id = ingredients.ingredient_id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=ccfbd2838775fc0f69775ef86ab29093

Comment: Thank you, will try and let you know. Just a quick question: you asked for specific version of MySQL. Does it mean this type of query will be slightly different for some versions of MySQL (which would be kind of problem), or this query simply is not supported by some older versions?

Comment: @toxpal *this query simply is not supported by some older versions* - starting from MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB 10.2.1.

Comment: After a year of using this solution, now I need to fetch all the sub-ingredients of MULTIPLE ingredients at once. After 1 day of modifying query, I either get errors or query runs indefinitely. In short, I need to fetch sub-ingredients of ingredients that are stored in other table. 

My first solution was to change `WHERE ingredient_id = 3` to `WHERE ingredient_id IN (SELECT ingredient_id FROM other_table)` - query runs indefinitely. If I remove `WHERE ingredient_id = 3` and use WHERE clause in some other place, it either returns errors or query runs indefinitely.

Comment: @toxpal Another question - new topic. Of course, you may refer to this topic if you think that this is reasonable. Also I recommend you to create a fiddle with new structures and data and provide the link and desired output into your new topic.

Comment: @Akinna - thanks for the suggestion, just posted and included a link to DB Fiddle - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71495533/recursive-join-to-the-same-table-using-where-clause-from-additional-table