# Recursive join to the same table using where clause from additional table

Tags: sql, join, recursive-query, self-join

Question is related to [Unlimited join to the same table until exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67329885/unlimited-join-to-the-same-table-until-exists/67330209?noredirect=1#comment126364336_67330209) but brings an additional table to the query. Tables:

`ingredients` - contains ingredient IDs and names

```
ingredient_id|ingredient_name
1            |Water
2            |Salt
3            |Fancy Sauce
4            |Spices
5            |Pepper
6            |Chili
```

`ingredients_to_ingredients` - contains optional sub-ingredients for each ingredient

```
ingredient_id|mapped_ingredient_id
3            |1
3            |2
3            |4
4            |5
4            |6
```

`meals_to_ingredients` - contains ingredients (which may contain sub-ingredients) for each meal

```
meal_id|mapped_ingredient_id
1      |1
2      |2
3      |4
```

To get sub-ingredients (if any) for specified ingredient (let's say #3 - Fancy Sauce), I use:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT *
         FROM ingredients_to_ingredients 
         WHERE ingredient_id = 3
       UNION ALL
         SELECT ingredients_to_ingredients.*
         FROM ingredients_to_ingredients
         JOIN cte ON cte.mapped_ingredient_id = ingredients_to_ingredients.ingredient_id )
SELECT ingredients.ingredient_name
FROM cte
JOIN ingredients ON cte.mapped_ingredient_id = ingredients.ingredient_id;
```

And get the list:

```
Water
Salt
Spices
Pepper
Chili
```

Working demo - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=0303d2ae8cded77053d87a0f31d9c374

Often I need to fetch sub-ingredients of multiple ingredients stored on other table - `meals_to_ingredients`. After a day of re-writing query, I was able to achieve this:

- Query works indefinitely
- Query returns errors
- Query returns 0 records
- Query returns absolutely all records

How do I rewrite query so it returns ingredients (and sub-ingredients) of let's say two random meals? I can post links to my non-working examples of modified query at DB Fiddle if needed.

Edit: Updated with desired output. Let's say new query randomly selects meals #1 and #3.

Meal #1 has mapped ingredients #1, #2 (`meals_to_ingredients` table), and these ingredients have no sub-ingredients (no records in `ingredients_to_ingredients` table)

Meal #3 has mapped ingredient #3 (`meals_to_ingredients` table), and this ingredient has sub-ingredients #1, #2, #4 (`ingredients_to_ingredients` table), while sub-ingredient #4 itself has further sub-ingredients #5, #6 (`ingredients_to_ingredients` table again).

So the result of all ingredients should be:

```
Water (ingredient_id - 1)
Salt (ingredient_id - 2)
Fancy Sauce (ingredient_id - 3)
Water (ingredient_id - 1)
Salt (ingredient_id - 2)
Spices (ingredient_id - 4)
Pepper (ingredient_id - 5)
Chili (ingredient_id - 6)
```

In fact, I will only need a unique list of ingredients, but I have no problems writing a query which filters duplicated records, so the example result above includes all the ingredients for easier understanding how query should work.

Comment: Provide desired output with detailed explanation (describe the whole links chain).

Comment: Updated as requested

Comment: *Meal #1 has mapped ingredients #1, #2 (meals_to_ingredients table)* I do NOT see mapping to #2... I see 1->1, 2->2, 3->4. The same about *Meal #3 has mapped ingredient #3*.

Comment: I also updated DB Fiddle link in original question to include some more records, so it better represents my actual DB structure - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=0303d2ae8cded77053d87a0f31d9c374

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( 
    SELECT meal_id, mapped_ingredient_id ingredient_id
    FROM meals_to_ingredients
  UNION ALL
    SELECT cte.meal_id, iti.mapped_ingredient_id
    FROM cte
    JOIN ingredients_to_ingredients iti USING (ingredient_id)
)
SELECT cte.meal_id, ingredient_id, i.ingredient_name
FROM cte
JOIN ingredients i USING (ingredient_id)
-- WHERE cte.meal_id IN (1, 3)
ORDER BY 1,2
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=ee26da089c9bb2e5046fea0bc29041ff

Comment: To be honest, I don't fully understand how this query works, but it seems to produce the results I need, so I will analyze it step by step and hopefully will learn more. Greatly appreciate your time and efforts being so helpful and writing such a complex query for a random guy on the Internet

Comment: So I'm running this code on actual production DB, and... query runs indefinitely. Each of tables has between 1500 and 2000 records and then server just stops responding (query runs indefinitely), even if I uncomment `WHERE cte.meal_id IN (1, 3)` part (so it should only select 2 meals). Any ideas?

Comment: @toxpal *I don't fully understand how this query works* https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=a0731941171e3c5ad76e38bc4fa0bcbf *Any ideas?* Provide complete real tables structures (the outputs of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;`). I think that there is no suitable indices simply. *Each of tables has between 1500 and 2000 records* - dump the data (make tables copies and drop excess columns) using `SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE`, then ZIP the structures (see above) and data files and upload to somewhere (for example, to GoogleDrive).